# To convert datatype of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, casting

Please guide me how i can convert a vector of string

```
std::vector<string> strVect; --> std::vector<float or double> flVect;
```

(e.g. strVect contains values like { "0.1111", "0.234", "0.4556"})

into a vector of floats using c++.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do but I bet `std::transform` combined with `boost::lexical_cast` would do the job.

Comment: Thanks can you give me its syntax.

Comment: @user986789: "Thanks can you me the codez". FTFY.

Comment: @user986789: http://bit.ly/SWseKZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution without using boost:

```
std::vector<string> strVect;
//...
std::ostringstream ss;
std::vector<double> flVect( strVect.size() );
for( size_t i = 0; i < strVect.size(); ++i )
{
    ss.str(strVect[i]);
    ss >> flVect[i];
}
```

Comment: You have to clear the string stream in every iteration. Otherwise this won't generate the desired output.

Comment: What about the even simpler `ss.str(strVect[i])` instead of `ss << strVect[i]`, which would make the clearing unneccessary and the use of a `std::ostringstream` more appropriate (and in the end would be worth an up-vote).

Comment: @ChristianRau I fixed that too, although I'm not sure this makes the example easier to grasp :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the existing answers, a very easy way is to use C++11 string conversion functions and C++11 lambdas:

```
std::vector<string> strVect = ...;
std::vector<float> flVect(strVect.size());
std::transform(strVect.begin(), strVect.end(), flVect.begin(), 
               [](const std::string &arg) { return std::stof(arg); });
```

And analogous for `double`, just with `std::stod`, of course.

Comment: The first wont work. `stof` is overload and you have to cast it to the correct type. And `flVect(strVect.size())` probably has no overhead here, but I prefer `vector::reserve`. That way you don't end up with an unexpected performance hit if this ever becomes a generic context.

Comment: @pmr Indeed, cppreference.com was lying to me (I should have realized myself that nothing working on `std::string` is really working on `std::string` alone).